# How do I get Gridview to render THEAD?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

How do I get the `GridView` control to render the `<thead>` `<tbody>` tags? I know `.UseAccessibleHeaders` makes it put `<th>` instead of `<td>`, but I cant get the `<thead>` to appear.

Comment: FYI: UseAccessibleHeader is "true" by default, so you don't need to set it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.useaccessibleheader.aspx

Answer (score 198, accepted):

This should do it:

```
gv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

Comment: The `HeaderRow` property will be `null` until the `GridView` has been data bound, so make sure to wait until databinding has occurred before running the above line of code.

Comment: As comment below, with ASP.NET 4.5 at least after binding isn't late enough - it works in OnPreRender however.

Comment: I have a gridview with custom sub headers added. Each of these sub headers do show data from the data source. The reason I wanted to render `thead` is to use it in jQuery. However after rendering header, the `tbody` doesn't seem to be available. What may be missing in my case?

Comment: I found there was still problems during postback and placed the code in the databound event which addressed all scenarios.

Comment: I bring my data from a database when user clicks on a button. In that case the gridview is missing the thead tag. Any help?

Comment: Must add  gv.DataBind();  before.

Comment: Add the ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" attribute to the GridView control if you want to render a grid with no rows.

Answer (score 34):

I use this in `OnRowDataBound` event:

```
protected void GridViewResults_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) {
        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Who designed these terrible controls?

Comment: I inserted your code into the OnRowCreated event and got it to work correctly.

Comment: This is the best solution because it removes the risk (and required check) of the TableSection being null if no rows are within the DataSource.

Comment: Fyi, if the `GridView` is within an `UpdatePanel` and an async-postback is caused by some other control then the `OnRowDataBound` event won't be raised thus the code in this answer won't be executed, resulting in the `GridView` reverting to rendering without `<thead>` tags... _sigh_. To target this case, shove the code from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/309119/1204599) into the gridView's `PreRender` event handler (much like [ASalvo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/808819/1204599) suggests).

Comment: This is the correct answer, as it properly uses the WebForms workflow.

Answer (score 10):

The code in the answer needs to go on `Page_Load` or `GridView_PreRender`. I put it in a method that was called after `Page_Load` and got a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: You can also put in `DataBound` event. `grid.DataBound += (s, e) => { grid.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader; };`

Comment: Don't know if this is different in .NET 4.5 now... but I am getting the HeaderRow being null in both _DataBound and _PreRender event handlers.  This might be related to the fact I am using ASP.NET Web Forms new "Model Binding" feature in the gridView.

Answer (score 7):

I use the following code to do this:

The `if` statements I added are important.

Otherwise (depending on how you render your grid) you'll throw exceptions like:

> The table must contain row sections in order of header, body and then footer.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if ( (this.ShowHeader == true && this.Rows.Count > 0)
      || (this.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty == true))
    {
        //Force GridView to use <thead> instead of <tbody> - 11/03/2013 - MCR.
        this.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
    if (this.ShowFooter == true && this.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //Force GridView to use <tfoot> instead of <tbody> - 11/03/2013 - MCR.
        this.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
    }
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

The `this` object is my GridView.

I actually overrode the Asp.net GridView to make my own custom control, but you could paste this into your *aspx.cs* page and reference the GridView by name instead of using the custom-gridview approach.

FYI: I haven't tested the footer logic, but I do know this works for Headers.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
protected void GrdPagosRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody;
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
    }
}
```

This was tried in VS2010.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but, here's an interpretation of MikeTeeVee's answer, for a standard gridview:

aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    OnPreRender="GridView_PreRender">
```

aspx.cs:

```
    protected void GridView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;

        if ((gv.ShowHeader == true && gv.Rows.Count > 0)
            || (gv.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty == true))
        {
            //Force GridView to use <thead> instead of <tbody> - 11/03/2013 - MCR.
            gv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }
        if (gv.ShowFooter == true && gv.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //Force GridView to use <tfoot> instead of <tbody> - 11/03/2013 - MCR.
            gv.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function and use that function in your `PageLoad` event like this:

The function is:

```
private void MakeGridViewPrinterFriendly(GridView gridView) {  
    if (gridView.Rows.Count > 0) {          
        gridView.UseAccessibleHeader = true;  
        gridView.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;  
    }  
}
```

The `PageLoad` event is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            MakeGridViewPrinterFriendly(grddata);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery to add it.  This avoids the problem with TableRowSection.TableHeader where  gets dropped on PostBack.

`$('#myTableId').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("#myTableId tr:first")));`