# Asp.Net Building Impressive DataGrid \ ListView (Webform)

Tags: datagrid, webforms

can someone pls give me a reference about building impressive(or just beautiful ) datagrid \ listview.

all my purpose is to show data (not adding data or editing data).

i have one condition that on click on a specific column data it would reference another page (a detailed view).

i have a list object that contains all the data to bind with it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This [website](http://icant.co.uk/csstablegallery/tables/80.php) has some nice CSS table designs. You could pick one of those, download the appropriate CSS file, include it in the page where you have your table and that should be all.

If all you have is just a simple table, I would recommend you use a GridView rather then a DataGrid, mostly because it's easier to make the GridView render the header/footer sections of the table, which are required for the above CSS files to work. (check this questions for example, [How do I get Gridview to render THEAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309101/how-do-i-get-gridview-to-render-thead))

ListView gives you even more control then a GridView, but you have to type some more code yourself (HeaderTemplate, ItemTemplate, AlternatingItemTemplate, etc). If you have scenarios where you need more control over how the table is rendered the ListView would be better choice, but based on what you said (simple tables) I would recommend the GridView