# Why does GridView not render the header row as thead after postback?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, tableheader

Setting `TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader` after the grid is bound works initially, putting the header row in `thead`. After a postback (where the grid is not re-bound) the header row reverts to the table body. I expect the header row to stay in thead; can someone explain why this is not the case or what I am doing wrong?

Sample:

Click the button to cause a postback. The header is not orange after the postback since it's not in `thead` anymore.

**aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="gridtest.aspx.cs" Inherits="ffff.gridtest" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
    thead th { background-color:Orange;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    &nbsp;this button is here just to trigger a postback</div>
    <asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**code**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ffff
{
    public partial class gridtest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gv1.DataBound += new EventHandler(gv1_DataBound);
            if (!IsPostBack) { BindGrid(); }
        }
        void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (gv1.HeaderRow != null)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(gv1.HeaderRow.TableSection); // still TableHeader after postback
        }
        void gv1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (gv1.HeaderRow != null)
            {
                gv1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
            }
        }
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            gv1.DataSource = this.Page.Controls;
            gv1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get Gridview to render THEAD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309101/how-do-i-get-gridview-to-render-thead)

Answer (score 19):

Use the Pre_Render_Complete event instead to add the table section. This will ensure the `thead` section is always added. As you are currently doing it on DataBound the section will only be added when the data is bound.

```
protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gv1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gv1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;                
        }
    }
```

Feel free to change the row check I use to checking the Header Row exists as you currently do.

Comment: I'm using a standard `GridView` rather than inheriting from it so I attached an event handler to `PreRender` and this works. I don't understand why though- `gv1.HeaderRow.TableSection` has a value of `TableHeader` before and after this assignment. Is there something going on within the setter that's responsible for making this render correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant give you an answer to why this is the case, only that it works. My OnPrerenderComplete overide is actually at a page level. Often if I have several grids on a page I will load up the all table head sections in one spot. I might have a little investigation/experiment into the mechanics of this in light of your follow up question

Comment: Interesting. When Stepping through my page OnPreRenderComplete shows HeaderRow.TableSection as TableBody before the assignment, ensuring ViewState was enabled. ViewState is saved after the PreRenderComplete event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) so that isn't the issue.

Comment: I needed to use this in a Usercontrol, so I used the OnPreRender event and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you.  It still threw exceptions for me, so I expanded your approach to fit my needs.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19846059/555798

Answer (score 5):

You must set TableSection after DataBind method.

```
 gv1.DataSource = this.Page.Controls;
 gv1.DataBind();
 gv1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that. The question is why does the grid render the default way after a postback, even when `TableSection` is still set as `TableHeader`.

Comment: From http://forums.asp.net/t/1004097.aspx?GridView+HeaderRow+null+
 - HeaderRow is null when your datatable is empty (or, in this case, this.Page.Controls is empty)

Answer (score 3):

Just put the below code in prerender event of gridview

```
protected void gv_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (gv.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        gv.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        gv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
}
```