# jQuery add <thead> and add <tbody>

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add `<thead>` and `<tbody>` this using jQuery?

the problem is my table has 1 or 2 th rows?

```
$('#myTable tr:has(th)').wrap('<thead></thead>');
```

---

```
<table id="myTable">

<tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr>
<tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr>

<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: a [table header](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/th) generally has one `thead` element as a sibling of `tbody`, not multiple heads inside a row.

Comment: @jbabey not every browser adds a thead element. They do add a tbody.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you need to do is remove the rows and append them to a thead element

```
var myTable = jQuery("#myTable");
var thead = myTable.find("thead");
var thRows =  myTable.find("tr:has(th)");

if (thead.length===0){  //if there is no thead element, add one.
    thead = jQuery("<thead></thead>").appendTo(myTable);    
}

var copy = thRows.clone(true).appendTo("thead");
thRows.remove();
```

[jsFiddle exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/B4bv6/)
​

Answer (score 7):

use wrapAll instead of wrap

```
$('#myTable tr:has(th)').wrapAll('<thead></thead>');​
$("#myTable thead").prependTo("#myTable")
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It will result in `<tbody><thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead></tbody>`

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q224z/) showing this is broken and an incorrect solution.

Comment: You can try this:

$table.find('tr:has(th)').wrapAll('<thead></thead>');
$table.find('thead').prependTo($table);

Comment: if you found your way here because you are trying to use an asp datagrid or gridview, you can use this solution instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309101/how-do-i-get-gridview-to-render-thead

Answer (score 0):

```
function createTable(data) {
    var str = "";
    str += '<table><thead>';
    str += '<tr><td>Pos</td><td>Ref</td></tr></thead><tbody>';
    for (var item in data.recentList) {
        str += '<tr>';
        for (idata in data.recentList[item]) {
            str += '<td>' + data.recentList[item][idata] + '</td>';
        }
        str += '</tr>';
    }
    str += '</tbody></table>';
    $('body').append(str);
}
```

Working version that creates a table from an array